# How to write the following query codefirst with entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework and I dont know how to write the following query using code with C#

```
SELECT 
    Managements.OrderID, Books.bookName, 
    Managements.BookReturnDate, Managements.Money 
FROM 
    Managements, Users, Books 
WHERE 
    Users.UserID = Managements.Username_UserID 
    AND Books.bookID = Managements.Book_bookID
```

Comment: You're looking to use methods like `.Join()`, `.Where()`, and `.Select()`.  There are existing tutorials to get you started on using Entity Framework and using LINQ, and you are very much encouraged to make an attempt.  You may be surprised at how easily you can pick it up when you try.

Comment: could you provide some sources?